# How do I traverse a syntactic parse tree to extract noun phrases using OpenNLP in R?

Tags: r, tree, opennlp

I want to extract noun phrases out of each sentence in a set of documents using R. I used openNLP in R to generate parse trees for each sentence. I need help to traverse the parse tree to extract noun phrases. Here is my code:

```
install.packages("openNLP")
library(openNLP)
install.packages("openNLPmodels.en", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type = "source")
library(openNLPmodels.en)
install.package("tm")
library(tm)

s <- c("The touch pad of my laptop does not work.", 
       "The boy saw the man with the binoculars.")
s <- as.String(s)
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
parse_annotator <- Parse_Annotator() 
a <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
p <- parse_annotator(s, a) 
ptexts <- sapply(p$features, '[[', "parse") 
ptrees <- lapply(ptexts, Tree_parse) 
ptrees
```

Here are the output trees:

[[1]]
(TOP
  (S
    (NP (NP (DT The) (NN touch) (NN pad)) (PP (IN of) (NP (PRP$ my) (NN laptop))))
    (VP (VBZ does) (RB not) (VP (VB work)))
    (. .)))

[[2]]
(TOP
  (S
    (NP (DT The) (NN boy))
    (VP
      (VBD saw)
      (NP (NP (DT the) (NN man)) (PP (IN with) (NP (DT the) (NNS binoculars)))))
    (. .)))

My goal is to extract NP at any level. For example, "the man with the binoculars", "the man". I searched R openNLP documentation and stack overflow, but couldn't find solutions using R. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try my wrapper package: https://github.com/trinker/parser

Comment: Hi Tyler, thank you very much for providing the package. This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I encountered an error while following the installation steps at github: (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load_gh("trinker/parser"). The error message is "ERROR: dependency 'textshape' is not available for package 'parser'. Could you please let me know how I can fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Use `pacman::p_load_gh(c("trinker/textshape", "trinker/parsent"))` I added this to the readme thanks for the catch.

Comment: The new instruction works! I am able to extract subject, predicate verb and object. I tried to extract the head NP "The touch pad" from the subject "The touch pad of my laptop" using             get_phrase_type_regex(x, "NP") %>%
+   take() %>%
+   get_phrase_type_regex("NP") %>%
+   take() %>%
+   get_leaves()                                                                                           but it output the top level NP "The touch pad of my laptop". Is there a way to extract the head NP from the subject? Thanks for your help!